# How to initialize the power method-inverse iteration?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anybody help me, what is the selection criteria while selecting initial vector while using power iteration/inverse iteration method to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors numerically and which are the condition which must fulfill while choosing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you pick a vector at random.

The power method will work for any starting vector $v_0$ *except* vectors that have no component in the direction of the eigenvector $w$ you are trying to find (the one with largest magnitude eigenvalue, for ordinary power iteration, or smallest-magnitude eigenvalue, for inverse iteration.)

Now if you pick $v_0$ randomly, the probability that $v_0\cdot w=0$ is zero. In practice there will be numerical error whenever you perform the matrix-vector multiplication, which makes it even less likely that you will get "unlucky." But if you're worried you can always run the algorithm with multiple random starting guesses.

Comment: @Rajat I am still confused how "random selection" ?.Can you tell me please more specifically.And i will appreciate/thankful if you can define it by some mathematics. I sure that there may be some specific criteria to which initial eigenvectors is selected.thanks

Comment: The only criterion is that $v_0\cdot w\neq 0$, which of course you cannot check in advance since you don't know $w$. In practice you use `rand()` et al to populate $v_0$. For a proof that power iteration converges for almost every $v_0$, see Theorem 8.2.1 in Golub and van Loan 4th Edition.